# How to instantiate a tile on the end of another moving tile?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, infinite-loop, objectinstantiation

I'm trying to create an "Endless runner" game, where the player remains stationary on the origin of the axes while the tiles scroll with a fixed speed on the Z-Axis as they are instantiated.
The script attached spawns 5 tiles at the start while already scrolling at the speed set in the GameManager and then keeps on spawning tiles based on a fixed spawning rate.

The problem I'm facing is calculating the correct distance between the tiles after the first five are instantiated so that each end of a tile is overlapped.

I'm attaching what I've written so far, in the TileManager script, in the hope that someone knows how to proceed, or perhaps knows a different method. Thanks!

```
public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] tilesArray;
    [SerializeField] private int tilesToSpawn = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float zPosSpawn = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float tileLength = 20f;
    [SerializeField] private float scrollCoefficient;

    private float timeSinceLastSpawned;
    private float spawnRate;

    void Start()
    {
        //scrollingObjectsSpeed = -1,5f
        spawnRate = GameManager.Instance.scrollingObjectsSpeed * -1;
        SpawnLogic();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;
        
        if (timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate)
        {
            timeSinceLastSpawned = 0;
            SpawnTiles(Random.Range(1, tilesArray.Length));
        }
          
    }
    private void SpawnLogic()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tilesToSpawn; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    SpawnTiles(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    SpawnTiles(Random.Range(0, tilesArray.Length));
                }
            }
        }

    private void SpawnTiles(int tileIndex)
    {
        scrollCoefficient = (GameManager.Instance.scrollingObjectsSpeed * -1f) * spawnRate ;
        Instantiate(tilesArray[tileIndex], transform.forward * zPosSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        zPosSpawn = (zPosSpawn + tileLength) -  scrollCoefficient;
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with a previous game and I will suggest to you the best way to solve this.

### **1**

create a list of GameObjects to save your tiles.

```
List<GameObject> tiles;
```

### **2**

save your tiles in the list

```
tiles.Add((GameObject)Instantiate(tilesArray[tileIndex], transform.forward * zPosSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
```

### **3**

check every tile to see its position

```
for(int i = 0; i < tiles.Count; i++)
    {

         if(grids[i].transform.position.z <= lowerPosition)
        {
            
            DestroyObject(tiles[i]);
            tiles.Add((GameObject)Instantiate(tilesArray[tileIndex], transform.forward * zPosSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

**DestroyObject()** is just a simple function, but remember to remove the grid:

```
void DestroyObject(GameObject tile)
{
    
    Destroy(grid);
    tiles.remove(tile);
}
```

Hope it is useful!

Comment: Alright! Many thanks for your answer man, it's really helpful! The only thing that I don't get is why you wrote the grids list. What is its purpose if I already have the tiles list?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I changed it